# Layout design help Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using a web service which gives me a list of all the people in alphabetical order. I am showing this list in a `Spinner`.

I would like to separate the list into sections by the first letter. The user would then select the section (e.g. A, B, etc.) of that list of people that will be loaded in spinner.

What is a good and intuitive way to design that alphabet view for the user?

I thought about two drop downs: one for letters, and one for the list of people but that doesn't seem to improve it.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was: Created two listviews side by side with alphabets as well as people

like this[image]

with which you can scroll alphabets one side and corresponding people will load on other side.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Based on what your describing it sounds like 
an expandable List View showing letter the first letter of the name and expanding to reveal all persons with that name.

Take a look at this pic.
http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/09/expandablelistview-on-android.html[image]